# Fantasy art book from 1980s

Tags: story-identification, art

I'm trying to find a fantasy art book from the 1980s just for nostalgia to see if it's as strange as I remember. It was a smallish hardback book that just contained illustrations. The subject was fantasy/sci-fi but not traditional D&G or sci-fi.

I remember having the book in the early 1980s but it might have been published earlier. This was in the UK. I remember the illustrations being strange but I can't really remember much about them.

I've looked through lots of vintage fantasy art but can't find any that I recognise. The closest in style would be this:

[image: example of image style]
[Pinterest, 1970s Fantasy Art: More Rodney Matthews Awesome](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/328410997829412147/)

Comment: [Paper Tiger](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pubs_not_in_series.cgi?29060) put out a slew of art books, some in trade, some in hardcover, some themed, some [single-artist](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pubseries.cgi?1953).  (Though it doesn't look like they did any of Rodney Matthews until the 1990s.)  Unfortunately it's very hard to search them or find even a representative set of thumbnails of their content.

Comment: One thing you can do is click through one of the collections and see the list of works it contains.  For example Matthews' [*In Search of Forever*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?288237) lists all the works; since many of them were originally book covers, if you click on, say ["Sanctuary"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1411816) it will tell you it's a variant of ["Anackire"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1538794) which shows the cover art.  So you can check out various collections that way.

Comment: I had a framed poster of Matthews' "[Stronghold](https://neilirving73.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/tumblr_lxfxcz0weg1r1xkjlo1_1280.jpg)" for years; I quite liked his art.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look through those links and let you know if I find the book.